# How to set the read and write providers for JSON using JAX-RS in Apache Tomee plus

Tags: json, tomcat, jax-rs

I can return simple text from my Pojo but it fails when I changed to return JSON. I have the correct annotations for produces and consumes in my methods and I checked that the content negotation between Jquery and the server is correct.

It seems to be that the conversion to JSON just fails. I copied the Jackson jars in webapps/tomee/lib. I also tried the lib folder of my application.

The error message when doing a GET:

```
No message body writer has been found for response class <myClass>
```

This error is fired by the JAXRSOut Intercepter class

The error when doing a Post is:

```
No message body reader has been found for request class <myClass>
```

This error is fired by the JAXRSUtils class

- Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I made this work by listing the JAX-RS providers in conf/system.properties file of TomEE. Then I added the jars to TomEE's lib folder. The documentation in the website states that one should drop the jars on webapp/tomee/lib, but that did not work for me.

**conf/system.properties**

```
openejb.cxf.jax-rs.providers = org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider, org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
```

Jars I dropped:

- jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.9.jar
- jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.jar
- jackson-jaxrs-1.9.9

Answer (score 0):

If you use jersey you could try Genson library http://code.google.com/p/genson/.
Latest version 0.92 provides automatic detection of json support in jax-rs web services with jersey.
You should only have to drop the jar and voila! :)

Comment: Thanks eugen. I had found a solution with Jackson so I did not test your solution.